# Alternative to SimplyScroll with some features

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I'm looking for an alternative to SimplyScroll (it's deprecated) with some features. I'd like a continuous, automatic carousel of boxes/images that stops when you pass over the mouse pointer (SimplyScroll can do it), and can move it when clicking and move your pointer (this doesn't). Of course, nowadays everything must be responsive. I had searched a lot but I hadn't found anything with all features, for example when you can move it with your mouse, the carrousel is not continuos (it doesn't move pixel by pixel, but box by box), or you cannot put it in vertical, and so on. Maybe I couldn't find it because I didn't use the right words, english is not my mother tongue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about an exact alternative for SimplyScroll. As their website has mentioned these type of carousels are rare now a days. There are much better and responsive (touch enabled) carousel plugins.

Here are some good examples of auto scrolling carousels:

1. https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/

2. http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/demo.php

You just have to google "auto scroll carousel jquery plugins".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already had seen your links and they aren't exactly what I'm looking for. Cheers